# Pgfplots change color based on sample index

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gradient

I would like to illustrate the stretching that a parametrization induces. I am using pgfplots to plot a parametric curve, and I would like to change the color of the curve based on the sample index (for example, if I draw a curve with 80 samples, I would like to be able to say that if a sample has an even index, then the line segment should be red and if it has an odd index the line segment should be blue).

I have faked this effect with the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1,xmax=8,
        ymin=-1,ymax=2.5,
        xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
        axis lines=middle,
    ]

        \addplot[domain=0:.5, samples=20, ultra thick, red] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});
        \addplot[domain=0.5:1, samples=20, ultra thick, blue] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});
        \addplot[domain=1:1.5, samples=20, ultra thick, red] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});
        \addplot[domain=1.5:2, samples=20, ultra thick, blue] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

but I don't want to have to manually specify a bunch of plots with different domains.  Ideally, I could also specify a color gradient and use that to determine the color of each piece of the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter

\newcount\alternatinglineparity
\newdimen\tempx
\newdimen\tempy
\tikzset{alternating/.code={\let\tikz@plot@handler\pgfplothandleralternatinglineto}}
% Copied from \pgfplothandlerlineto.
\def\pgfplothandleralternatinglineto{
    \pgfkeys {/pgf/plots/@handler options/.cd,
        start=\relax,
        end macro=\relax,
        point macro=\pgfutil@gobble,
        jump macro=\relax,
        special macro=\pgfutil@gobble,
        % only difference is \alternatinglinetolinehandler instead of \pgfpathlineto:
        point macro=\alternatinglinetolinehandler , 
        jump=\global \let \pgf@plotstreampoint\pgf@plot@line@handler@move
    }
}
\def\alternatinglinetolinehandler#1{
    \pgfpathmoveto{#1}%
    % I added this line -- initialize parity to even:
    \global\alternatinglineparity=0\relax 
    \global\let\pgf@plotstreampoint=\alternatinglineto%
}
\def\alternatinglineto#1{
    \global\advance\alternatinglineparity1\relax
    \ifodd\alternatinglineparity\relax
        \color{blue}
    \else
        \color{red}
    \fi
    \tempx=\pgf@x % save registers
    \tempy=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathlineto{#1}
    \pgfusepath{draw} % this screws up the registers
    \pgf@x=\tempx % restore them
    \pgf@y=\tempy
    \pgfpathmoveto{#1} % set up next line segment
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1,xmax=8,
        ymin=-1,ymax=2.5,
        xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
        axis lines=middle,
    ]

    \addplot[domain=0:2, samples=80, ultra thick,alternating] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output (note that the actual result isn't jagged, that's just an artifact of the picture):

[image]

Comment: I've been looking at `point meta=\coordindex`  It looks like it might lead to a cleaner solutions, but I am not sure how to set the line segment color according to the `point meta`

Comment: @JasonSiefken Yeah this sort of low-level solution is really flexible, but also a bit hard to understand. At least it doesn't change any `pgfplots` code.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with coordinate filters, I was able to achieve the effect another way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{>=latex}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1,xmax=8,
        ymin=-1,ymax=2.5,
        xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
        axis lines=middle,
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\samplestep}{2}

        \addplot[domain=0:2, samples=80, ultra thick, red,
        x filter/.code={%
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\orig}{\pgfmathresult}
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\modcoord}{mod(int(mod(\coordindex, 2*\samplestep)),2*\samplestep)}
           \pgfmathparse{\modcoord <= \samplestep ? \orig : nan}
        }, unbounded coords=jump] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});
        \addplot[domain=0:2, samples=80, ultra thick, blue,
        x filter/.code={%
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\orig}{\pgfmathresult}
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\modcoord}{mod(int(mod(\coordindex, 2*\samplestep)),2*\samplestep)}
           \pgfmathparse{\modcoord == 0 || \modcoord >= \samplestep ? \orig : nan}
        }, unbounded coords=jump] ({-(x+1)*x*(x-3)*(1+x^2)/4},{-x*(x-1)*(x-2)*4*(1+x^3)/4});

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I filter coordinates based on `\coordindex` and graph the function twice, each time throwing away half the coordinates.  `\samplestep` affects how many line segments are drawn each time.  `\samplestep` must be at least 2.

I found I needed to use `mod` twice in my pgf code because using `mod` once didn't produce correct results.